# get consecutive win lose results

Tags: mysql

I'm currently struggling with this problem where I need to get the latest consecutive win or lose result of a member

```
tbl_results
result_id   member_id   result  match_date
1           1           W       2014-12-28
2           1           W       2014-12-21
3           1           W       2014-12-14
4           1           L       2014-12-17
5           1           W       2014-11-30
6           2           L       2014-12-28
7           2           L       2014-12-21
8           2           L       2014-12-14
9           2           W       2014-12-17
10          2           L       2014-11-30
11          3           W       2014-12-28
12          3           L       2014-12-21
13          3           W       2014-12-14
14          3           W       2014-12-17
15          3           W       2014-11-30
```

After many hours of researching in the internet, I have come up with this

```
SET @mID = 0;
SET @num = 1;

//this variable will hold what to count
SET @wtc = 'W';
SET @wl = 1;

SET @consecutives = 'FALSE';

SELECT
    tbl_results.member_id,

    //I add here a row number for each member_id so that i can determine if the iteration has changed members or not
    @num := IF(@mID = tbl_results.member_id, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
    @mID := tbl_results.member_id AS temp_m_id,

    //from here onwards, I started using some programming syntax and logic
    //I plan to convert it later to the correct MySQL syntax

    //new member detected
    IF @num = 1 THEN
        //determines what to count (the wins or the loses)
        @wtc := IF(tbl_results.remarks = 'W', 'W', 'L') AS what_to_count,
        //consecutives started
        SET @consecutives = 'TRUE';
        DISPLAY 1 in win_lose column
    ELSE
        //if it is still consecutives
        iF @consecutives = 'TRUE' THEN
            IF @wtc = 'W' THEN
                IF tbl_results.remarks = 'W' THEN
                    DISPLAY 1 in win_lose column
                ELSE
                    //consecutive wins has been broken
                    @consecutives = 'FALSE';
                    DISPLAY 0 in win_lose column
                END IF
            ELSE
                IF tbl_results.remarks = 'L' THEN
                   DISPLAY 1 in win_lose column
                ELSE
                    //consecutive loses has been broken
                    consecutives = 'FALSE';
                    DISPLAY 0 in win_lose column
                END IF
            END IF
        ELSE
            DISPLAY 0 in win_lose column here up to the next member
        END IF
    END IF
FROM
tbl_results
```

I know that the query above is definitely WRONG, i have no experienced in using mysql variables, I just read about it a while ago, but I'd figured that i show you what i've come up in case you have suggestions

What I am aiming using my query above is to output something like this

```
member_id   row_number    temp_m_id     win_lose     what_to_count
1           1             1             1            W
1           2             1             1
1           3             1             1
1           4             1              0
1           5             1              0
2           1             2             1            L
2           2             2             1
2           3             2             1
2           4             2              0
2           5             2              0
3           1             3             1            W
3           2             3              0
3           3             3              0
3           4             3              0
3           5             3              0
```

Then the final output using the COUNT() function would be this

```
member_id   consecutives what_to_count
1           3            W
2           3            L
3           1            W
```

the what_to_count column determines if the consecutives is for wins or for loses

ex.

1 - has 3 consecutive wins

2 - has 3 consecutive loses

3 - has 1 win

Please be aware that the tbl_results is a table resulted from a sub query (it holds the records that sorted the original table by member id and by dates)- i just do not add it in this example to make it shorter

you can point me where are the wrongs in the query that i've shown, even though i already know that it really has so many errors, please forgive me for that.

You can also rewrite my query using the proper mysql syntax or use your own

If you have better ideas or any other methods aside from what i've shown as long as it will output the consecutive wins and loses, please let me know. please. I would really appreciate it. Thank You Very Much

Comment: Is it really plausible that id might follow a different order from match_date?

Comment: @Strawberry, i can already handle the match date order - it is stored in the tbl_results_table, please don't mind the order of the match date anymore

Comment: I can not see three consecutive wins for member_id = 1. If ordered by `match_date` member_id 1 has W,W,L,W,W

Comment: @johnkernelle If match_date is no longer relevant to the problem, I suggest you amend the question to suit.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it maybe a typing error, I just manually type it so that i can show you an example the dates is ordered descending for each member

Comment: When ordering on `result_id`, member_id = 3 has three consecutive wins (13,14,15) - why do you expect 1 in the final result?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, the member_id 3 has won on 2014-12-28 but has a lose in it's previous match (2014-12-21)

- before, it has 3 consecutive wins, then it lose, then won again - so it's consecutives is reset to 1

Comment: @Strawberry, i am sorry, i will edit the question title

Comment: The question still includes references to match date. Is match date still relevant to the problem?

Comment: You are confusing me. First you claim "consecutive" is based on the `result_id`, now you claim it's based on `match_date`. So which is it now?

Comment: @horse_with_no_name - it is based on match date .. sorry for troubling you

Comment: In that case your expected output for member_id = 1 is wrong.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, o sorry about that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, please if you have any ideas or suggestions, please let me know, i just want the final output to determine the latest consecutives of wins or loses, i don't care what methods is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really confusing. So instead, consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS results;

CREATE TABLE results
(result_id   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,member_id   INT NOT NULL
,result  CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO results VALUES
(1 ,1,'W'),
(2 ,1,'W'),
(3 ,1,'W'),
(4 ,1,'L'),
(5 ,1,'W'),
(6 ,2,'L'),
(7 ,2,'L'),
(8 ,2,'L'),
(9 ,2,'W'),
(10,2,'L'),
(11,3,'W'),
(12,3,'L'),
(13,3,'W'),
(14,3,'W'),
(15,3,'W');

SELECT a.member_id
     , a.result_id start
     , MIN(c.result_id) end 
     , a.result
     , MIN(c.result_id) - a.result_id +1 total
  FROM results a
  LEFT 
  JOIN results b
    ON b.member_id = a.member_id
   AND b.result = a.result
   AND b.result_id + 1 = a.result_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN results c
    ON c.member_id = a.member_id
   AND c.result = a.result
   AND c.result_id >= a.result_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN results d
    ON d.member_id = a.member_id
   AND d.result = a.result
   AND d.result_id - 1 = c.result_id
 WHERE b.result_id IS NULL 
   AND c.result_id IS NOT NULL
   AND d.result_id IS NULL
 GROUP 
    BY a.member_id
     , a.result_id
     , a.result; 

+-----------+-------+------+--------+-------+
| member_id | start | end  | result | total |
+-----------+-------+------+--------+-------+
|         1 |     1 |    3 | W      |     3 |
|         1 |     4 |    4 | L      |     1 |
|         1 |     5 |    5 | W      |     1 |
|         2 |     6 |    8 | L      |     3 |
|         2 |     9 |    9 | W      |     1 |
|         2 |    10 |   10 | L      |     1 |
|         3 |    11 |   11 | W      |     1 |
|         3 |    12 |   12 | L      |     1 |
|         3 |    13 |   15 | W      |     3 |
+-----------+-------+------+--------+-------+
```

This solutions assumes that result_id is contiguous, but there are workarounds if it isn't. Feel free to pick the bones out of that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm most used to SQLite, however here follows a solution:

```
-- Create a copy from tbl_result appending a column GR_BEGIN
-- GR_BEGIN will be 1 when a different result from previous happen
CREATE TABLE t1 AS SELECT *, COALESCE(prev!=result,1) AS gr_begin FROM (
  SELECT *, (
    SELECT result FROM tbl_results AS x1 WHERE result_id=(
      SELECT MAX(result_id) FROM tbl_results x2 WHERE result_id<tbl_results.result_id AND member_id=tbl_results.member_id
    )
  ) prev FROM tbl_results
) AS x3;

-- Create another table, with another column GR
-- GR will hold sequence number for consecutive results (for each member)
CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT *, (
  SELECT SUM(gr_begin) FROM t1 x1 WHERE result_id<=t1.result_id AND member_id=t1.member_id
) gr FROM t1;

-- Finally, following query will return last result and count of consecutive
-- results for each member:
SELECT member_id, result last_result, COUNT(*) consecutive
FROM t2
WHERE gr = (SELECT MAX(gr) FROM t2 x1 WHERE member_id=t2.member_id)
GROUP BY member_id
```

Check it in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89a22e/1)!